# EditorTemplates not working on IE10

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I added a hint template to a textbox. The template is working fine on firefox and chrome but it is not showing up on IE10

**Model property:**

```
[Display(Name = "Age*" , Prompt="Enter Number: ")]
public string Age { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
@Html.EditorFor(c => c.Age, new { @class = "form_txt" })
```

**Template:**

```
Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\String.chtml:
@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new
{
    @class = "form_item txt txt_gray box_gray_focus rounded_corner",
    placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark,
    title = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Description
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`Html.EditorFor` does not have an implementation that takes an `htmlAttributes` object as an argument. You are using the following implementation of the method, which means you are passing `class = "form_txt"` as ViewData to your EditorTemplate.

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    Object additionalViewData
)
```

What you need to do is to define the `class` attribute in the EditorTemplate, and use `Html.EditorFor` like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(c => c.Age)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use EditorTemplate and just use a TextBoxFor in your View... does it works in IE10?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new
{
    @class = "form_txt",
    placeholder = "Here enter your Age",
    title = "This is the title"
})
```

IE till IE9 didn't implemented the Placeholder, but it [looks like IE10 should support it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441188.aspx).
As placeholders are not replacement for labels, it is just a hint, you should not rely on them anyway.

Said that, there are some jquery plugins to handle this on not supporting browsers or versions.

- http://code.google.com/p/jquery-placeholder-js/
- https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder
- http://corymathews.com/html5-placeholder-in-ie/